# Sending message from wearos app to phone: onMessageRecieved not called after update targetSdk

Tags: android, wear-os

After change phone app targetSdk from 29 to 30 ,`MessageClient.OnMessageReceivedListener` `onMessageReceived` not receive message from wearos app.
if I set targetSdk to 29, it's works.

here is my test code :
wearos app part

```kotlin
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable
import com.hltek.hzdatalayerdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException

import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await
import java.util.*

/**
 * wearos app
 */
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    private var TAG = "MainActivity"
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val job = Job()
    private val scopeIO = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            scopeIO.launch {
                var str = Date().time.toString() + "_ time"
                sendLiveCountData(str)
            }
        }

    }

    //send message to phone
    private suspend fun sendLiveCountData(str:String){
        var ctxt = this
        val LIVE_COUNT_PATH = "/live_count"
        try {
            var nodes = Wearable.getNodeClient(ctxt).connectedNodes.await()
            for (n in nodes) {
                if(n.isNearby) {
                    println(">>> send to nearby node node: ${n.displayName}")

                    Wearable.getMessageClient(this)
                        .sendMessage(n.id, LIVE_COUNT_PATH, str.toByteArray()).await()
                }
            }
        } catch (cancellationException: CancellationException) {
            Log.d(TAG, ">>> sendLiveCountData cancellationException:.${cancellationException.localizedMessage}")
            // Request was cancelled normally
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, ">>> sendLiveCountData failed:.${throwable.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
}
```

phone part:

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.*
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets


// on the phone
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MessageClient.OnMessageReceivedListener
   {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Wearable.getMessageClient(this).addListener(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Wearable.getMessageClient(this).removeListener(this)
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Wearable.getMessageClient(this).addListener(this)

    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: MessageEvent) {
        try {
            if(p0.path == "live_count"){
                println(">>> live_count message")
            }
            val s1 = String(p0.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            Toast.makeText(this, s1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println(">>>> onMessageReceived event received:$s1")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(
                ">>> Handled in sending message back to the sending node"
            )
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

All code:
https://github.com/haozes/HZDataLayerDemo

I checked a lot of google documents, but it didn’t show that play-services-wearable is related to the targetSdk. It’s very strange. Now I can’t upgrade the targetSdk.
I tested it on Galaxy watch 4 and Samsung F52 phones (android11).

anyone get the same problem?

Comment: Finally i got the problem is  China device , the bug can only be produced in China phone. 
and i got a workaround to fix it:
Use service to listen message